# Multiple template template paremeters for template class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-templates

Is it possible to pass two template classes into a template class?

I am looking to create a class that holds two different `std::tuple<std::vector<>>`.

I am beginning to suspect that what I want to achieve can not be done, but I can not find anything that says otherwise.

Below is the code I am  working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
struct Typelist
{
  static constexpr std::size_t size { sizeof...(Ts) };   
};

template<class, class> class World;

template<template<typename... Arg1> class T1, template<typename... Arg2> class T2>
class World<Typelist, Typelist>
{

private:
  std::tuple<std::vector<T1>...> m1;
  std::tuple<std::vector<T2>...> m2;
};


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    using TL1 = Typelist<int, char, double>;
    using TL2 = Typelist<float, unsigned int, bool>;

    World<TL1, TL2> w2;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/S24uor)

Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?
If not, is there a possible alternative?

Comment: Use of `World<Typelist, Typelist>` is not correct since `Typelist` is not a class. You can use `World<Typelist<args1>, Typelist<args2>>` but it's not clear from your post what would be sensible values for `args1` and `args2`.

Comment: Please explain to me what the purpose of the tuple is, it's not at all clear to me, because as written there's only one type within, and you're misusing the `...` operator?  There's no parameter pack to expand?  Are you trying to do `std::tuple<std::vector<Arg1>...>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think you might mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
struct Typelist
{
  static constexpr std::size_t size { sizeof...(Ts) };   
};

template <class, class>
class World;

template <typename... Arg1, typename... Arg2>
class World<Typelist<Arg1...>, Typelist<Arg2...>>
{

  private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Arg1>...> m1;
    std::tuple<std::vector<Arg2>...> m2;
};


int main() {
  using TL1 = Typelist<int, char, double>;
  using TL2 = Typelist<float, unsigned int, bool>;

  World<TL1, TL2> w2;
  return 0;
}
```

The changes made:

First, the template specialization was changed to two bare parameter packs, this is doable, because the parameter packs are filled by the template matching engine based on the types with the `Typelist`, so it is unambiguous.  You cannot use the specification you used previously because then you only have access to `T1` and `T2`, you do not have access to the names of the inner parameter pack arguments.

Second, I changed how the data members of `World` were defined, so that `m1` and `m2` are tuples of vectors of types.

Third, you can get rid of `Typelist` entirely and use a `tuple` directly.  Unless it's doing something not featured in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template <class, class>
class World;

template <typename... Arg1, typename... Arg2>
class World<std::tuple<Arg1...>, std::tuple<Arg2...>>
{

  private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Arg1>...> m1;
    std::tuple<std::vector<Arg2>...> m2;
};


int main() {
  using TL1 = std::tuple<int, char, double>;
  using TL2 = std::tuple<float, unsigned int, bool>;

  World<TL1, TL2> w2;
  return 0;
}
```